# how to 'clear' text in an HTML input box using CSS alone, when user enters text

Tags: html, css

I need to have an input box on a web page where a user can enter their name. The input box should show some text (pref in grey) saying something like 'login name' which when the user types, disappears, using CSS only, no JS, just like the input box at the top of http://www.rottentomatoes.com/ saying "Search movies, TV, actors, more...".

I've drilled into this RT example using the f12 stuff in firefox, I can barely make sense of it and can't reproduce the behaviour. Any help welcome, thanks.

Edit: Thanks so much everyone. Placeholder was the info I needed. End result with blank-on-focus was:

```
<style type="text/css">
::-moz-placeholder {  /* Firefox 19+ */
   color: grey;  
}
input:focus::-moz-placeholder {
    opacity: 0;
}
</style>
<input name="search" placeholder="user name here" 
            id="search-term" type="text">
```

Comment: You can't do it with css. You need javascript of the html attribute called `placeholder`.

Comment: @mimo look at the two answers below, they both will do it :/

Comment: @AdamBuchananSmith not if you use IE 8 or 9 ;)

Comment: Who uses IE8 or 9?!?!.... 1.7% of the population is the correct est.... After jan. 2016 IE8 through IE10 will no longer be supported. So let me ask you this @mimo Why in the world would we care about the crappy A$$ IE 8? block it and move on....

Answer (score 3):

What you are looking for is the HTML input's (and textarea's) [`placeholder`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input#attr-placeholder) attribute:

```html
<input type="text" placeholder="Search">
```

Answer (score 1):

This interaction can’t be done soley with CSS. You can use the [`placeholder` attribute on `<input>` elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input#attr-placeholder):

```
<input id="login-name" type="text" placeholder="enter login name">
```

With CSS, you can [style placeholder texts](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/style-placeholder-text/) afterwards.